# 2 same BlocBuilders with same StreamBuilders on two different pages, second one not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using a Bloc for Profile named 'ProfileBloc'. I have stream of User in its States.
I have two screens in my app,

```
1. Main Screen
2. Profile Screen
```

I am using this exactly same bloc builder in both screens,

```
BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileStates>(
 builder: (context, profileState) {
  if (profileState is ProfileInitialState) {
    return Column(
     children: [
       StreamBuilder<MakaniUser>(
        initialData: null,
        stream: profileState.makaniUser,
        builder: (context, user) {
         if (user.data != null &&
           user.connectionState ==
           ConnectionState.active) {
            return Text(user.data.mobile);
           } else
              return Text('nothing received');
             }),
            ],
           );
        }
      return loader;
     },)
```

Problem: Only one blocBuilder works at a time. i.e.
If I remove the first one from MainPage, it works on the second screen (Profile Page) and vice versa.

Would appreciate any help.